# Is there a shortcut to check nested property existence

Tags: javascript

I dont know if `a.b` is set. I want to do something only if `a.b[0].c` is true. I can do something like this:

```
if (a.b && a.b[0] && a.b[0].c) {
    // ...
}
```

Is there a shortcut to check nested existence? Can I simplify this kind of condition?

Comment: I think this is the clearest and most concise way to do what you want.  And this is why I love coffeescript so much.  In CS you just say `if a?.b?[0]?.c then ...`.  I really hope future versions of javascript incorporate more of the simplicities of coffeescript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to code golf, and one of the tricks we used is the following.

```
(myArray || [])[0] || 0
```

First, `myArray || []` is evaluated, if myArray exists, this returns it, if it doesn't, then it returns an empty array. Let's say myArray isn't defined. Next, the `[][0] || 0` expression gets evaluated ans because `[][0]` is undefined, this returns 0.

In your case it could be used the following way:

```
((a.b || [])[0] || {}).c || {}
```

This returns an empty object if something's undefined.

I'm not saying you should use this (in fact, you shouldn't), I just want to show you, that there is a smaller solution.

Update:

If [tc39](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/blob/master/README.md) gets through, then you'll have a much better solution using optional chaining:

```
a.b?[0]?.c
```

Comment: I love this, but can't upvote it as I don't see it as a practical solution if only because it's hard to read while skimming code.  But what a beautiful one-line solution!

Comment: haha, I love this too :)

Comment: @jusopi this probably goes in the hackery category.